# pyCharm refactoring python class attribute name, does not rename all attribute usages

Tags: python, refactoring, renaming, class-attribute

Considering the following:

```
class test:
    att = 7


def print_class(class_instance):
    print(class_instance.att)


if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    t = test()
    print_class (t)
```

`print_class` expects a class `test` instance as a parameter, but this is not typed.

Now I'd like to rename by refactoring `att` 
However,

> print(class_instance.**att**)

will not be renamed, as the editor has no clue this is the same attribute.
This will be discovered only at run time.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: You could use type hints, either as annotations or in docstrings, to tell PyCharm what you're expecting:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe even a docstring will suffice in this case

Comment: @DeepSpace docstrings are a *kind* of type hints, per both my comment and the docs I linked to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe . Not sure I fully understand, type hints, on all forms, are used by the editor, for coding purposes. They are not used by the interpreter.  am I right?

Comment: it is weird that the refactor works when it is a method, but it doesn't work for attributes. Do you @jonrsharpe know why?

Answer (score 0):

As @jonsharpe suggested in the comments, type hints will solve this issue.

However, if you don't want to use type hints, you can use a docstring that attaches a type to `class_instance`:

```
class test:
    att = 7


def print_class(class_instance):
    """

    :param test class_instance:
    #       ^ specify type here
    :return:
    """
    print(class_instance.att)


if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    t = test()
    print_class(t)
```

After refactoring:

```
class test:
    attribute = 7


def print_class(class_instance):
    """

    :param test class_instance:
    :return:
    """
    print(class_instance.attribute)


if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    t = test()
    print_class(t)
```

Comment: I was not aware of that. Not sure I fully understand, type hints, on all it's forms, is used by the editor, for coding purposes. am I right?

Comment: Interesting, but this does not solve the problem if I have usages in many functions. It would take a lot of time to do this in all of them. And also is annoying to have to add docstrings even to very simple functions.

Comment: I edited the question to include how to use typehints, which is less verbose than docstrings, but still requires to do it in every usage.